# UISegmentedControl: segment overlapping when pass data back

Tags: swift, view, uisegmentedcontrol

thanks Duncan C. I edit my question:

i have a ViewControllerA with a 3 segments SegmentedControl, on ViewControllerB you can delete one segment and go back to VCA.
when I do so, I have, in VCA, 2 segments (the new segments after deletion) over the 3 segments (the 3 segments initially loaded).

[VCA before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rSrk.png)

[VCA after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzYei.png)

I understand that it has to do with the view cycle, the initial ViewDidLoad persists, but even passing through viewWillAppear I still have this result.

this project is not a real project, just a test to solve the problem I have on my initial project.

my code for VCA:

```
class VCA: UIViewController, Info {
    // array which contains the name for the segmentedControl
    var array = ["Peter", "Bob", "Jim"]
    var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        setView(array: array)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // delegate protocol: receive data from VCB
    func passData(array: [String]) {
        self.array = array
    }
    
    func setView(array: [String]) {
        segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: array)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 50
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(segmentedControl)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                                        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
                                        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
                                        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
                                        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20)])
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        let destinationVC = VCB()
        destinationVC.array = array
        destinationVC.infoDelegate = self
        destinationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

my code for VCB:

```
class VCB: UIViewController {
    // array which contains the name of the segments
    var array = [String]()
    // delegate to send data back
    var infoDelegate: Info!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setView(array: array)
    }
    
    func setLabel(array: [String]) -> String {
        var labelText = "the array contains"
        for name in array {
            labelText += " \(name)"
        }
        return labelText
    }
    
    func setView(array: [String]) {
        
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        
        label.text = setLabel(array: array)
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                                        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
                                        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)])
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Delete the first name in the array", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                                        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 40),
                                        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.centerXAnchor)])
    }
    
    @objc func backTapped() {
        array.remove(at: 0)
        infoDelegate.passData(array: array)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

with a protocol to send data back to VCB:

```
protocol Info {
    func passData(array: [String])
}
```

any ideas/help?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I gather VCA is view controller A and VCB is view controller B. You're saying that from VCB you delete one segment of VCA's segmented controller?

You should not mess with another view controller's views.

You will need to post your code and explain how the user navigates between view controllers in order for us to be able to help you.

(And by the way, those huge segmented controls look absurd. You should leave them at the standard height.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. I remove all segments of the UISegment before repopulating it with the new data received from ViewController B.

```
func passData(array: [String]) {
    self.array =array
    segmentedControl.removeAllSegments()
    segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: array)
}
```

If the solution seems to work, it is not very elegant.